Do you say "stand at the beginning of the queue" the same way we say "stand at the end of the queue"?
In the dictionary, "end" is used for both time and space. For example,
-They get married at the end of the movie. (time)
-The bank is right at the end of the street. (space)
Also in the dictionary, "beginning" seems to be used for time only. For example,
-They get married at the beginning of the movie. (time)
My daughter once asked me this question "can we go to the end of the universe?"
And I answered "the universe has no beginning and no end". But it seems like I was talking about time like that the universe has not starting and ending time.
But my daughter is talking bout space in the universe. Maybe, I could say "the universe has no starting and ending point".
Similarly, we can say "stand at the end of the queue".
What is the opposite of the above sentence?

"stand at the beginning of the queue" is not correct right?

If not, then what is it?

I seem to remember On Topic questions have to reflect some real-world problem. But it's unnatural to ask how to tell someone to stand at the beginning of the queue! Obviously the people who've already been waiting patiently after having created the beginning / head / start of the queue aren't going to like being displaced! On the other hand, your point about "beginning" seems to be used for time only is obviously not true. For example, the beginning of this comment is a metaphorically spatial, non-temporal reference to my [earlier] sentence about On Topic questions.

...the beginning of the Nile.

Natural in some instances. In American English: "I got to go to the head of the line at the airport because I was on crutches. My broken leg was good for something at least".

Let's use another example: Please pass this to the person at the beginning of the queue.
Beginning of the queue is a valid phrase though it is less common than front of the queue.
Both constructions found in Google Books are mostly for descriptions in computer programming, but I managed to find two hits for the front usage for non-computer programming descriptions, one on page 1 and another on page 3.
These phrases can be used in context like our example here: Please pass this to the person at the front of the queue.

Yes, at the front of the queue is definitely the idiomatic version.

"Pass it to the front" is common in classrooms and other contexts as well as queues, so it's much more natural here. "Beginning" might be used if you're talking about how the queue formed, e.g. if someone started queuing 2 nights ago and gradually people lined up behind them, the first person would be "at the beginning of the queue". Another alternative is "the person who is first in the queue", particularly if the queue is disorganized or not in line and you want to serve somebody.

Thanks, @Stuart F.  I like 'Pass it to the front.' for its conciseness.  It renders the rest of the words redundant.

Yes, both work fine. You could also say "Queue up at the front" or "Queue up at the back".
